# Lightbox not loading

Tags: jquery, external, lightbox

```
// Lightbox
    $('a.lightbox').click(function () {
        $.getScript("js/lightbox.js", function () {
            alert('Load Complete');
            $("a.lightbox").lightbox({
                'type': 'iframe',
                'overlayOpacity': 0.6,
                'width': 940,
                'hideOnContentClick': false
            });
        });
    });
```

I want to load script on first request, but it doesn't seem to work, the page just redirects to the linked website, does not open iframe in lightbox.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using `getScript`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `return false` to prevent the event from propagating:

What is actually happening is that when the link is clicked, the code executes, but the event is finished, at which point the `href` attribute of the link (if it exists) is then redirected to.

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $.getScript("js/lightbox.js", function () {
            alert('Load Complete');
            $('a.lightbox').click(function () {

               $("a.lightbox").lightbox({
                  'type': 'iframe',
                  'overlayOpacity': 0.6,
                  'width': 940,
                  'hideOnContentClick': false
               });
               return false;
            });  
        });
        $('a.lightbox').click();
   });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Great, works, but the lightbox does not load in one attempt, can I add a manual delay just for the first request? thanks!

Comment: Hmm..nothing happens, lightbox doesn't open.

Comment: Erm...lightbox opens now but on second-click. BTW, can the jquery's $.delay() function be used here somehow? Thanks!

Comment: No, `delay` only works with animation and CSS style chaining.